# How do I upload a file with article custom fields?

Tags: development, joomla-4.x, custom-field, file-upload

I've created a custom field plugin type "file" and am using it as custom field on articles so users can upload a file (the "media" type file does not suit my needs).

It looks and works OK while editing the article, but how do I manage to handle the upload itself?

In other words, when I save the article, `jform[com_fields][my-file-field-name]` is included on the submitted form data, but I do not know where to place the actual code to handle the uploaded file.

Comment: Now, you will start to understand why Joomla is not delivering Joomla with all of the fields at core. :)

Comment: @Zollie I found a solution :)
Just need some time to answer my own question with a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: I am curious about what you found and your solution, a detailed answer could help a lot of people later.